# DBGrid stop current Row moving

Tags: delphi, delphi-5, dbgrid

Using d5, TDBGrid, SQLite3 and ZEOS. Database has 2000 items, one Column is an "Active" as Boolean, a second Column is "ItemName" as Text, and IndexFiledNames is "ItemName'

OnDblclick toggles "Active" On/Off and all works as expected for the **Data**. Active changes from True to False and back again.

But, if I double-click on the last visible Row of the DBGrid, to toggle the Active state --  after the toggle, the DBGrid moves that item Row to the vertical center Row-position of the grid. This is very confusing to a user with the Row they just double-clicked jumping around.

How can I stop the grid from moving that Row to the middle? This happens with all items that are on the last **visible Row** of the DGBGrid.

{EDIT} The remmed out items are attempts at reducing the issue - didn't work.

```
procedure TfrmMain.dbgridItemsDblClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  puItemsSelectedClick(Self);
end;

procedure TfrmMain.puItemsSelectedClick(Sender: TObject);
//var
//  CurrItem : String;
//  CurrIndx : String;
begin
  if dm.tblItems.RecordCount = 0 then
  begin
    myShowMsg('There are no Items in the Items List');
    Exit;
  end;
//  CurrItem:=dm.tblItems.FieldByName(fldItemGroupShop).AsString;
//  CurrIndx:=dm.tblItems.IndexFieldNames;
  dm.tblItems.DisableControls;
  try
//    dm.tblItems.IndexFieldNames:='';
    dm.tblItems.Edit;
    dm.tblItems.FieldByName(fldSelected).AsBoolean:=
      not(dm.tblItems.FieldByName(fldSelected).AsBoolean);
    dm.tblItems.Post;
//    dm.tblItems.IndexFieldNames:=CurrIndx;
//    dm.tblItems.Locate(fldItemGroupShop,CurrItem,[]);
  finally
    dm.tblItems.EnableControls;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: IIRC, think the reason for this is that the TDBGrid has a built-in bias (in how it's coded) to try and keep the current row near the vertical centre of the grid. When the change to the current row is saved, that triggers the dataset to notify controls that its cursor has scrolled and this prompts the grid to try to re-center the row and that's why it moves off the bottom. But, having said that, I've just tried what you describe, and the row doesn't move off the bottom, so could you add to your q please the code in your DBGrid1DblClick.

Comment: @MartynA Thanks Martin, but all pretty innocuous there, I think. :) When yours doesn't move, are you using D5? It may have been a "Feature" of the early versions. I have the enterprise version so I have the source code, but no idea where to start looking to stop the behavior. I have also tried a couple of dbgrid-Components, but they all seem to be based on TDBGrid and all do the same thing.

Comment: Is there some way to save the current Visible Row Number or position and then force the DBGrid to repaint it there after the Edit?

Comment: Using D7, but I'd be surprised if the grid behaves differently compared to D5.  Yes, there is a way of forcing the row value, I'm working on it but there's a bit more to it than just setting a new value.  Shall I post what I've got so far as an answer and fill it in later if I can?

Comment: related/duplicate of first "related" on the right (Delphi - restore actual row in DBGrid)

Answer (score 0):

The current row number and number of display rows of a DBGrid are protected properties,
so you need a "class cracker" type declaration in your code, like so:

```
type
  TMyDBGrid = Class(TDBGrid);

function TForm1.GetGridRow: Integer;
begin
  Result := TmyDBGrid(DBGrid1).Row;
end;

function TForm1.GridRowCount : Integer;
begin
  Result := TmyDBGrid(DBGrid1).RowCount;
end;
```

Having done that, place a TEdit and TButton on your form to input a new grid row number that's less than the current one.  Then try out the following routine:

```
procedure TForm1.SetGridRow(NewRow : Integer);
var
  GridRows,
  OldRow,
  MoveDataSetBy,
  MovedBy : Integer;
  DataSet : TDataSet;
  Possible : Boolean;
  ScrollUp : Boolean;
begin
  OldRow := GetGridRow;
  if NewRow = OldRow then
    Exit;

  ScrollUp := NewRow < OldRow;

  DataSet := dBGrid1.DataSource.DataSet;

  GridRows := TmyDBGrid(DBGrid1).RowCount;
  { TODO : Test the case where the DataSet doesn't have enough rows to fill the grid}
  { TODO : Check why grid reports one more row than it displays.
   Meanwhile ... }
  GridRows := GridRows - 1;

  // First check whether the NewRow value is sensible
  Possible := (NewRow >= 1) and (NewRow <= GridRows);
  if not Possible then exit;

  try
    if ScrollUp then begin

    //  First scroll the dataset forwards enough to bring
    //  a number of new records into view
    MoveDataSetBy := GridRows - NewRow;
    MovedBy := DataSet.MoveBy(MoveDataSetBy);
    Shortfall := MoveDataSetBy - MovedBy;
    if Shortfall = 0 then begin
      //  Now scroll the dataset backwards to get back
      //  to the record we were on
      MoveDataSetBy := -GridRows + NewRow;
      MovedBy := DataSet.MoveBy(MoveDataSetBy);
    end
    else
      MovedBy := DataSet.MoveBy(-MovedBy);
  end
  else begin
    MoveDataSetBy :=  -(NewRow - 1);
    MovedBy := DataSet.MoveBy(MoveDataSetBy);
    //  We need to know if the DS cursor was able to move far enough
    //  back as we've asked or was prevented by reaching BOF
    Shortfall := MoveDataSetBy - MovedBy;
    if Shortfall = 0 then begin
      // The DS cursor succeeded on moving the requested distance
      MoveDataSetBy := NewRow - 1;
      MovedBy := DataSet.MoveBy(MoveDataSetBy);
    end
    else
      //  it failed, so we need to return to the record we started on
      //  but this won't necessarily return us the same grid row number
      MovedBy := DataSet.MoveBy(-MovedBy);
    finally
      DBGrid1.Invalidate;
    end;
```

My earlier suggestion, to do a direct assignment to the grid row by "TmyDBGrid(DBGrid1).Row := NewRow;" was based on a mis-recollection, because in fact that seems to do nothing very useful.

The algorithm following "if ScrollUp" is made complicated by the fact that we're not depending on a meaningful RecNo.  What this involves is checking whether the dataset cursor can be moved by a sufficient amount in the direction *opposite* the one we want to move the grid row in, to scroll the DS cursor relative to the rows in the grid, without hitting EOF or BOF - if either of thiose happens, we just move the DS cursor back to where it was and give up trying to scroll the grid.

For ScrollUp, the logic is:

- First move the dataset cursor to the last row in the grid
- Then move it forwards some more, by the difference between the old and new Row values.
- Then move it back by an amount equal to the number of rows in the grid less the new row value.

If all that succeeds, the current row will move to the grid position requested by the NewRow value.
Of course, the code combines the first two of these steps.  At first, I thought this code was nonsense, because the algebraic sum of the values used for the DataSet.MoveBy()s is zero.  In fact, 
it's not nonsense, just a bit counter-intuitive.  Of course the distances add up do zero, because we want to get back to the record we were one; the point of doing the DataSet.MoveBy()s at all is to shake loose, as it were, the grid's grip on the current record and then return to it.  This is incidentally why there's no point in doing what I usually when moving off the current record and then returning to it, namely DataSet.GetBookmark/GotBookmark/FreeBookmark and indeed using those will defeat the code's intended effect.

I'm using a ClientDataSet, btw, not a ZEOS one, but that shouldn't make any difference.

Btw, the local DataSet variable is to access the grid's dataset without using Delphi's infernal "With ..." construct.

Incidentally, your comment about "Rows div 2" reminded me: I don't think it's the grid that tells the dataset, ISTR it's the Datalink associated with the grid which tells the dataset how many records it should allocate buffers for.  Then, in TDataSet.Resync, you'll notice

```
if rmCenter in Mode then
  Count := (FBufferCount - 1) div 2 else
  Count := FActiveRecord;
```

and then take a look how Count is used later in the routine; your theory may be spot on.  Maybe put a breakpoint on "if cmCenter in Mode"  and see if it gets called from where your grid acts up.

Btw#2, even if this code hasn't helped, this article might http://delphi.about.com/od/usedbvcl/l/aa011004a.htm

Comment: Thanks, I will mess with that. It is a little outside my knowledge area, but trial and error always serves me well. I look forward to anything you can add. I'll hold off on the "Answer" in case you post more. Thanks.

Comment: Getting nowhere fast on my own. :) It seems the only time the selected row doesn't move is when the selection is within 1 or 2 rows of the middle of the Visible Rows. Both up and down. Pretty much anywhere else moves the final row back to the center. No reliable RecNo unless no-indexes and/or no-filtering both of which I need at different times. :( I have found a few other posts online for the same misery, but nothing yet working. If I un-rem the stuff in my code it gets better, but still not reliably 100%. Thanks.

Comment: I do have an AutoInc. If I can save that AutoInc for VisibleRow 1, is there some after the Edit, way we can force it to repaint the dataset starting with the saved AutoInc at VisibleRow 1? With Disable/try/Enable there should be no visible movement. Even when filtered or indexed, it should stay the same AutoInc at VisibleRow 1, as I am only changing the state of a Field within the Record. The user cannot index on the Selected Column so there should be no changes to the item-sequence. Not sure how to do that, but just walking the dog and thinking time. :)

Comment: Thanks, I will try that. I am pretty sure it is not Zeos, as I have now tried it with Interbase and BDE. I have also tried several 3rd party DBGrid Components and all the same, probably because they are based on TDBGrid. I even stripped down to a new app with just the BDE and stock TDBgrid and it does it. Seems to be a feature of the D5 Borland Component. I have tried it running on XP, win7, win8 and win8.1 all the same. I have looked in the TDBGrid source for "Rows div 2" etc seeing if I can find anything that positions the Focus to the middle Row. Nothing. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I just tried my project in D5 and can't reproduce your prob.  If you can in a project using a TClientDataSet, put a copy on pastebin.com and post a link.  Oh, btw, I've deleted most of my comments, as I was involved in another set moved to chat earlier.

Comment: Added a bit to my answer about "Rows div 2" - you could be onto something.

Comment: Did you solve your problem? I'm facing the same challenge.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that my situation is like yours, but if you want to fix annoying grid centering (for example, if you react on user click and need to get to the record before or record below and then correctly get back), use this:

```
var oldActiverecord:=FDataLink.ActiveRecord;  
DataSet.DisableControls;
oldrecno:=Dataset.RecNo;//remember current recno
Dataset.RecNo:=SomeAnotherRecNoWhichYouNeedToGoTo;
//do what you like with this record
...
//then return to current
Dataset.RecNo:=oldrecno;//in this moment grid will center
var MoveDataSetBy:=oldActiverecord-FDataLink.ActiveRecord;//how much?
if MoveDataSetBy<>0 then begin
  DataSet.MoveBy(-MoveDataSetBy); //get back
  DataSet.Resync([rmCenter]); //center there
  DataSet.MoveBy(+MoveDataSetBy);//move cursor where we was initially
end;
DataSet.EnableControls;
```

Comment: Bingo! Here the virus is: `procedure TCustomADODataSet.SetRecNo(Value: Integer);
begin
  if RecNo <> Value then
  begin
    DoBeforeScroll;
    Recordset.AbsolutePosition := Value;
!!!!    Resync([rmCenter]);   !!!!
    DoAfterScroll;
  end;
end;`

Comment: Also, `Locate`, `Seek`, `FindRecord`, `GotoKey`, `GotoNearest`.....

Comment: Still, i fail to track, which variables/properties get changed either inside `TDBGrid` or inside `TDataLink` or inside `Windows HWND` ue to those ReSyncs - what STATE exactly gets changed there ?

Comment: With ADO Components key parameter that has to be recreated seems to be `Daatset.RecNo - Datalink.ActiveRecord`