# how to stay at current position in devexpress grid

Tags: delphi, devexpress

I use this code to save current selected record after refresh the dataset

```
bm := table1.GetBookmark;
try
  table1.Refresh;
  table1.GotoBookmark(bm);
finally
  table1.FreeBookmark(bm);
end;
```

But if I select a record at the middle of the grid, after executing this code it still be current selected record but it jump or make the grid scroll to be the first record in the current view. How I can keep current position ?

Comment: I use devart IBDAC component TIBCQuery components. For the grid I use devexpress grid.

Comment: If you're using TcxGrid, it would be best, I think to ask Devex.  My answer to this q (about TDBGrid) might give you some ideas: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25474102/dbgrid-stop-current-row-moving/25475398#25475398

Answer (score 0):

Remember current focused row and then set it after refresh.

Here is example for C# code, but I think, for deplhi it's the same:

```
var row = _gridView.FocusedRowHandle;
_gridView.RefreshData();
_gridView.SelectRow(row);
```