# How to get the middle row number in the current DBGrid View

Tags: delphi, dbgrid

Can anyone help me get the middle row number of the current DBGrid view?

I was able to get the following but could not get the row number of it. I also do not know what is this for.

`DBGRid1.CenterCurRowInView`

Update:
By the way, the grid is in scrolled view state.

Adding Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Please explain why you need the middle row number?

Comment: Ricky, you have already got an answer that you have marked as the correct one, but I would still ask you to clarify this: Do you mean the middle grid row number - 11 in your example as your grid can display 21 data rows? Or, do you mean the data set record number, that is displayed in the middle row, which happens to be 11 in the example as it is not scrolled? But could be e.g. 21 if the displayed data set rows are 11 - 31. I ask, as you emphasized that the grid is in scrolled state, which would be signifiant only in the latter case.

Comment: @TomBrunberg Yes Tom. 11 is an example only. It really depends on what visible scroll state. It could be a different number. I am referring to the grid display not from the dataset.

Comment: @fpiette I need the middle row number because there is the procedure I made when it goes after the middle row. It's unique requirement of mine but now is working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25475398/2663863) shows how to determine the current row number and number of rows in a DBGrid:

```
type
  TMyDBGrid = Class(TDBGrid);

function TForm1.GetGridRow: Integer;
begin
  Result := TmyDBGrid(DBGrid1).Row;
end;

function TForm1.GridRowCount : Integer;
begin
  Result := TmyDBGrid(DBGrid1).RowCount;
end;
```

This avoids the need for a class helper and  will work in Delphi versions which pre-date support for them.

Btw, the grid only has a unique "middle row" if the number of rows being displayed in the grid is odd, of course.  Also be careful of what you actually need, because the "middle row" is ambiguous if the number of rows in the dataset is less than the number of rows the grid can simultaneously display.

Comment: Your solution **is** an interposer class! And you have **two** helper functions (not class helper).

Comment: I see what you mean.

Comment: @MartynA Thanks for this answer! Though there are little issues that I have to fix myself but basically it works.

Answer (score 1):

The row count of the grid is given by the formula:

```
RowCount := DBGrid1.ClientHeight div (RowHeight + 1);
```

The middle row is obviously half that value (Also depends if you count the title row or not).

RowHeight is not published in DBGrid. To get hand on it, you can use an *interposer class*:

```
type
    TInterDBGrid = class(TDBGrid);
```

And use it like this:

```
RowHeight := TInterDBGrid(DBGrid1).RowHeights[0];
```

The interposer class must be defined **before** the form.

Comment: That is only so in non-scrolled grid ( when your top row in the vidget is the top row in the dataset ). P.S. class helpers can do insteaed of interposter class too

Comment: @fpiette Forgot to mention that the grid is scrolled. I just want to get the middle of the view height.

Comment: @RickyBelmont You are not clear in your comment. My solution gives the middle of the view height (The middle of what you see on screen). Isn't it what you need?

Comment: @fpiette Sorry. Yes! you are right!. I am looking for the middle of the DBGrid screen.

Comment: @fpiette I am not sure if I got it right. The `DBGrid1.ClientHeight` gives me 473 (I supposed this is not row numbers) while the `RowHeight` gives me 69 (this is my total rows including the scrolled ones). Now, with these numbers, I am getting 473/69 = 6.86. If I count the rows view count at runtime, I have 21 rows. So, the middle should be 11th row.

Comment: ClientHeight [of any control] gives the height of the usable area of the control in pixels. It is almost very close to the height you can see in the object inspector. This for example exclude the border. A row height of 69 pixels look very big! I have done a test on my system and RowHeight is 17 pixels. Could you edit your question and add a screen dump of the grid as you see it?

Comment: @fpiette Just a clarification. When you say `The interposer class must be defined before the form.` you mean frmMain.OnActivate or any other event of the form?

Comment: @fpiette I have added the screenshot you requested.

Comment: You marked MartynA answer as accepted (It is the same as mine, lacking the computation but with two functions to pack the code I gave) and you have not even up-voted my answer. So I won't answer anymore here.

Comment: @fpiette Sorry about that. I forgot. Yes, you have the same answer basically with MartynA. But yours is different approach.

Comment: Are you using my answer? The declaration `type TInterDBGrid = class(TDBGrid);` should be anywhere **above** `type TForm1 = class(...`.

Comment: @fpiette I am using MartynA's answer actually right now. Honestly, I was working on your answer when I encountered some issues and I raised a clarificatory question on your answer. I thought you were busy then so I tried Martyn's answer. If you can clarify my question to you above, perhaps I will give a try.